# How can I move the 'X' button to the end of the right side(inline with the left side of text)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get my head around CSS and practiced what I had learned. I go back and forth on the notes, googling here and there, tried the solution provided in the module but still it didn't go as the expected solution. I've been trying to move the 'x' button to the right as in the following picture. Below are the html and css code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
  margin: 8px;
}

.icon {
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="icon">!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?</div>
    <div class="close-button">✖</div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
    <button class="continue">Continue</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: add `float: right;` to `CSS` class `.close-button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this you can simply use `display:flex;` and `justify-content:space-between;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
  margin: 8px;
}

.right-header{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.icon {
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="icon">!</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="right-side">
        <div class="right-header">
        <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?</div>
        <div class="close-button">✖</div>
        </div>
          <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
        <button class="continue">Continue</button>
        <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div> 
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow ! I just learned new things today. So that's how to align two div's ! By adding another new container and putting the right setting for the container. It's just become more clear now. Thanks ! p.s: actually it's a little bit confusing since on the hint given from the instructor, we were asked to make sure to align the header, x button and the text. But still the final result will determine the result right ? As long we get the same final result. That will be fine. That's the beauty of programming :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could try two things,

give the close button

1:

`align-self: top right;`

2:

Give the close button

`position: absolute`

and then position it with the right margin

Answer (score 0):

You can add a float option to the current close-button element:

```
.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move that button with the `close-button` class inside the `div` with the `header` class, and change `display:inline-flex` to `display:flex`, like below.

> `display:flex` instead of `display: inline-flex` because `inline-flex` would take the smallest width it can take, so you wouldn't get what you are looking for.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.left-side,
.right-side {
  margin: 8px;
}

.icon {
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="icon">!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="header">
      <div>Are you sure you want to do that?</div>
      <div class="close-button">✖</div>
    </div>

    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
    <button class="continue">Continue</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this, i think it's the best solution for your case

```
 <style>
    .modal {
      background: white;
      width: 480px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      display: inline-flex;
      padding: 8px 8px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .close-button {
      background: #eee;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 16px;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
    </style>
```